# Not detecting two arrows pressed - java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem. I implemented some simple functions that are called when pressing arrows.

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {

            double t = p.getAngle();
            if(p.getIsTurning())
                t+=3;
            else
                t+=6;
            p.setAngle(t);
            p.setIsTurinig(true);

        }
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            p.setVelX(p.getVelX()+p.getAcceleration());
            p.setIsAccelerating(true);
        }       
}
```

When I press up arrow and then left, everything works well. However, when I press left arrow and then up arrow, then only the up arrow function is detected.

What might cause the problem?

Comment: Of course the first else if should be if

Comment: Then you should edit your code to indicate that.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. You should be using `Key Bindings` to handle specific events. Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard]() for more information and working examples that work with multiple keys pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Neither **if**'s will really detect that both the Left and UP Arrow keys are pressed simultaneously. The event will only return the **last** key pressed. Even when you press the UP arrow and then Left arrow keys, all you're really detecting is the LEFT arrow key. You could very well have pressed the DOWN and LEFT arrow keys and the same **IF** condition would fire.

One way to detect whether or not several keys are pressed simultaneously is to create boolean flags to indicate which desired keys are pressed and which are not but you will also need to utilize the **KeyReleased** event so as to falsify the necessary flags when a particular key is released. The boolean flags should be global to your Keyboard events, for example:

```
boolean keyOne = false;    // flag for LEFT Arrow key
boolean keyTwo = false;    // flag for UP Arrow key

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { keyOne = true; }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) { keyTwo = true; }

    if (keyOne && !keyTwo) {
        System.out.println("Only the LEFT Arrow key is pressed!");
    }
    else if (!keyOne && keyTwo) {
        System.out.println("Only the UP Arrow key is pressed!");
    }
    else if (keyOne && keyTwo) {
        System.out.println("Both LEFT Arrow and UP Arrow keys are pressed!);
    }
}

public void keyReleaseded(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { keyOne = false; }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) { keyTwo = false; }   
}
```

At least something to that effect...

Place your desired code into the (keyOne && keyTwo) **if** condition.